# DrawRect for iOS using Xcode is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I am trying to draw an ellipse but the drawrect method never gets called.  I'm not sure why the draw rect method is not being called i have

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

in the viewdidload (the only thing inside the viewdidload) and yet it never gets called.  Pretty sure I have done this before and it worked so i'm so confused!

here is my drawrect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   NSLog(@"called");
   CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
   CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
   CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

What am I missing? I'm also using the new Xcode 6

Comment: Show the code in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Did you add your view to the view hierarchy?

Comment: this is why I am so confused...all that is in the view did load is [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: Why does this question keep getting down voted I feel like it is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented `drawRect` in your custom view subclass? This method doesn't go in the view controller itself.

Comment: You are right.  I could literally slap myself I haven't done this in a long time!

Comment: Do you know, is there a way to get the coordinates of the entire line in an array.  Like every point it the line touches on the screen?

Comment: Please ask this as another question, so others can also help you!